# If I specify compatibility with Windows 8, 8.1, or 10 in my manifest, what changes?

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-8.1, manifest, windows-10

This page:

[Application Manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371711.aspx)

Lists certain changes that occur if you specifically flag your application as compatible with Windows 7. For example:

> **Windows 7**: To improve scalability and reduce thread counts, RPC switched to the NT thread pool (default pool). For Windows Vista, RPC used a private thread pool.
>   ...
>   **Windows Vista (default)**: For binaries compiled for Windows Vista and below, the private pool is used.

Are there any similar lists of changes that occur on newer versions of Windows (8, 8.1, 10) if you specify their supportedOS GUID in the manifest, vs not specifying one at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading Windows 7 documentation.  Try reading newer documentation, such as this one for Windows 8:

[App (executable) manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848036.aspx)

Windows 10 has not been released yet, so MSDN does not have much in the way of Windows 10 documentation yet.  However, the `supportedOS` guid for Windows 10 has been mentioned in some MSDN blogs, at least:

```
<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
```